# jQuery addition error

Tags: jquery

I have a strange error going on. This is the jQuery function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#new_customer").delegate(".kool", "keyup", function(event) {  
    var SelectProd = jQuery('.price, .qty',this);
    var price = jQuery('.price', this).val();
    var qty =   jQuery ('.qty', this).val();
    var amount = price + qty;
    var lineItemWrapperElement = SelectProd.parent().parent();
    jQuery("input.amount", lineItemWrapperElement).val(amount);
  });
 });
```

Instead of doing addtion "+" is concatinating. i.e  12+1 is coming as 121 what seems to be the problem?? any guidance would do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you concatenate strings. You have to convert variables to numeric type. I assume your price can be a float, so you can use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function:

```
var amount = parseFloat(price) + parseFloat(qty);
```

In order to fix the precision you can also use [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) after:

```
amount = amount.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 var amount = parseInt(price, 10) + parseInt(qty, 10);
```

or

```
var amount = parseFloat(price).toFixed(2) + parseInt(qty, 10);
```

Because, `.val()` returns string property and `+` has dual roll of adding and concatenation of string. Which depends on type of variables.

If `parseFloat()` or `parseInt()` depends on you, how you want your output.

Answer (score 2):

You are concatinating strings, so you have to convert them to numbers first

```
var amount = +price + +qty;
```

Comment: @bharath Yep, `+` before the variable in JS is the same as `Number(val)` which converts any basic type to number (not exactly to int or to float).

Comment: @VisioN- kool....any documentation or site u can recommend where i can learn all this in detail???

Comment: @bharath Sure, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) is the best source of information about it :)

Answer (score 1):

price and qty is a string parse it to float or any numeric type

```
var amount = parseFloat(price) + parseFloat(qty);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var amount = parseFloat(price).toFixed(2) + parseInt(qty, 10);
```